# How do I use Regex to check an array of URLs to see if I return to the original folder

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say we have an array of strings and each strings are either `./` or `../`, where `./` meaning entering the next level of the current folder, and `../` meaning going back to the upper level folder. So the array would be something like `[./, ../, ../, ./]`. And we want to check if we eventually return to the original folder.

I know this problem is quite simple. I tried to iterate the array and for each item I delete the last char in the string i.e. the '/' using `str.slice(0,-1)` then I count every '..' and '.' to see if they are equal.

However I feel somehow my code is brittle and really would like to see how someone can use regex to solve this problem.

```
let numOfGoingDeeper = 0;
let numOfGoingBack = 0;
arr.forEach(str => {
if(str.slice(0,-1) === '..') {
  numOfGoingBack++;
} else if(str.slice(0,-1) === '.') {
  numOfGoingDeeper++;
}
}
return numOfGoingDeeper === numOfGoingBack
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code already performs quite well. If you desire more regexiness and speed you could count the .match results.

```js
function pathFunction(arr) {
  let inputString = arr.join();
  let regex = /\.\.\//g; // To count and remove all ../
  
  let numOfGoingDeeper = (inputString.match(regex) || []).length;
  inputString = inputString.replace(regex);
  
  regex = /\.\//g; // To count all ./
  let numOfGoingBack = (inputString.match(regex) || []).length;

  return numOfGoingDeeper === numOfGoingBack;
}

console.log ( pathFunction(['../','./','../','./']) );
```

This isn't your question but just in case: In UNIX ../ does mean go up a directory but ./ represents the current directory. So a path .././.././ would be equal to the path ../../

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a Regex. You could perform a simple search/replace to change every "../" to -1 and every "./" to +1, then sum the results.

```js
var arr = ["./", "../", "../", "./"];

var new_arr = arr.map(x => x.replace("../", -1).replace("./", 1));

var deplacement = new_arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc + parseInt(val, 10), 0);

console.log(deplacement)
```